# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<'

Tags: php, javascript

```
<?php
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
document.write("If this text is displayed, your browser supports scripting
and JavaScript enabled!");
alert("Data is added successfully");
//-->
</script>
?>

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in php
```

actually i am inserting data into database and then this javascript button message should come, but its gives me above mention error.
This JV code runs perfectly alrite as html but gives me error if same is inserted in php. is it some error in php.ini or anything else? 
Newbie in php so seeking hlp in this.

Comment: .... this is just javascript with php tags around it. What is it supposed to do?

Comment: @andrewsi I guess a syntax error ? xD

Comment: If you want to display it as html, just echo it out `<?php echo "<script ...."; ?>`

Comment: `<?php` puts you into a PHP execution context, and then you feed javascript to the PHP parser. So yeah, you're getting syntax errors because you're running running PHP code - you're trying to run javascript code

Comment: This is an almost scary question...

Answer (score 6):

Its because you've opened a php tag with `<?php` then proceeded to write HTML/Javascript

As the `<` means something in PHP the first `<` of the `<script>` tag is causing the error.

Either remove the PHP tags as you don't have PHP inside them, or wrap your HTML in quotes and echo it out as a string

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
document.write("If this text is displayed, your browser supports scripting
and JavaScript enabled!");
alert("Data is added successfully");
//-->
</script>
```

Or

```
<?php
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
document.write("If this text is displayed, your browser supports scripting
and JavaScript enabled!");
alert("Data is added successfully");
//-->
</script>';
```

Although to be honest, unless you are going to add PHP to this there is no point in the second option. Just remove the `<?php` and `?>`

Edit (suggested by GolezTrol):

If you want to switch between HTML/Javascript and PHP you can do it all in the one page by toggling between the tags for example

```
<?php
$name = 'Frank';
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
document.write("If this text is displayed, your browser supports scripting
and JavaScript enabled!");
alert("Data is added successfully, <?= $name; ?>");
//-->
</script>

<?php
echo $name;
?>
```

*Note: To ward off comments from those that don't know about the PHP short tag `<?=` it is becoming a standard in PHP 5.4 and will always be available even if turned off in the .ini* file.

Comment: I'd choose the first method to output larger chunks of HTML anytime, because of smarter syntax highlighting by most editors, and not having to escape some characters. You may want to expand your answer to show how you can open and close PHP tags to toggle between HTML and PHP 'modus' whenever you want.

Comment: @GolezTrol Agree completely, infact I rarely if ever put blocks of HTML in variables.  I'd rather toggle between PHP and HTML as you said

Comment: echo suggestion works. thanks for helping me as these small-small things matters alot, when person is not in shape.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should read the basics of php before asking this kind of question. Take a look at http://www.php.net

The reason why the php interpreter complains is because you can't simply throw javascript code meant to be in an html page to it, and expect the interpreter to behave like a browser. IT doesn't know about html tags like  e and so on. It only knows php language.

Please, consider studying more php if you to use it. It is really easy.